# How to add this to my static folder?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Below is what I have in my head section in my base html page. This script works- just like how I want it to. How do I add the script to static folder? Like I want to create a seperate js folder and make file for this script.

```
    <head>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}reservation/css/main_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".asu").click(function(){
            var foo = $(this).text()
            alert(foo);
           });
        });
   </script>
   </head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do:

```
<head>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}reservation/css/main_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}reservation/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Now, in the file `main.js` (Assuming you want the folder structure to be `reservation/js` under the `{{STATIC_URL}}`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".asu").click(function(){
        var foo = $(this).text()
        alert(foo);
   });
});
```

Just make sure jquery is loaded before your custom js file.

Comment: glad i could help. Please do accept the answer if that was useful

Comment: In my above example, how would I pass the foo variable to a different page?

Comment: extract it into a javascript function, and pass that as an argument from the html file.

Comment: I am afraid, I don't understand your answer. I want to display the foo variable in another template. I am using jquery .post for that. I would like to know how to access the foo in a different template.

Comment: Since you are doing a POST, send the `foo` variable in the `context` from the view.